# Linearly Independent Unit Vectors

Tags: vectors

[image]

I know that if we think of u and v as two vectors in R^3, the magnitude of the dot-product of u and v is |u|v|cos(x), where x is the angle between them. If a set of vectors is linearly dependent, at least one is a multiple of the other which means (I think) they don't point in the same direction. This means (again, I think) that the range of u * v is R < |1|.

I just have two questions:

I don't know if that is the answer, my teacher explained it and this is how I interpreted it, but I'm not sure it is correct. So, is this the answer?

If it is the answer, how would I write that in interval notation? I learned interval notation a while back, but I forgot.

Comment: So looking at your notation, you have written
$$
R < |1|
$$
Perhaps you mean
$$
|R| < 1
$$ ? Because $|1|$ is just $1$, so adding the absolute value doesn't change anything.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. That was a typo. I meant |R|<1.

Comment: $(10,0,0)*(1,1,0)$=10....  These vectoris are independent....

Answer (score 0):

$u.v$ lies between $-1$ and $+1$. The required interval is $[-1,1)$. You also have to show that for any $t \in [-1,1)$ there exist linearly independent unit vectors $u$ and $v$ such that $u.v=t$. For this take $u=(1,0,0)$ and $v =(t,\sqrt {1-t^{2}},0)$.  [You cannot have linearly independent unit vectors $u$ and $v$ such that $u.v=1$. This is  a consequence of the condition for equality in Cauchy -Schwarz inequlity].

Comment: Ok, I understand a little. Does this mean that the answer is [−1,1)? Sorry, I'm just a little confused.

Comment: @Krithika Yes the answer is $[-1,1)$.